# UIPageViewController: pageViewController:spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation: not called

Tags: objective-c, ios5

my spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation-method is not called; therefore, the spine is always on the left, but I would like to have it in the middle... what am I doing wrong?

```
if ([UIPageViewController class]) {
    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc]
        initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
        navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
    self.pageViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

    NotesPageController *notesPageController = [[NotesPageController alloc]
        initWithNibName:@"NotesPageController" bundle:nil];
    NSArray *pageViewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:notesPageController, nil];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:pageViewControllers
        direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];

    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.pageViewController animated:NO];
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to provide more than one view controller in `pageViewControllers`.

Comment: that doesn't work for me, unfortunately... I also know an example where it's enough to provide one viewController... :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried setting the spine property manually?

To set the spine location, wrap one of these constants in an NSNumber object and set it as the value for the UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey key in the options dictionary passed to the initWithTransitionStyle:navigationOrientation:options: method.

Ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

Comment: although I don't know why that's necessary... it worked! thanks a lot!

Comment: It worked - thanks
NSDictionary *options = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid]
                                forKey: UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];
    
    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:options];

Comment: I have tried this one but still it is not getting call.... For min and max position it is working fine. But for mid position it is not calling. Only the blank page is coming

Answer (score 12):

Do you have the view controller that contains the code above properly inserted into the view controller hierarchy? Start by setting `UIWindow.rootViewController` and then call `addChildViewController:` on every controller in the hierarchy. That's what was necessary for me to get the rotation forwarding and the spine function called when retrofitting an iOS4 app.

**Edit:** I've discovered there is more to it than this. Apple has made this class rather difficult to use. The problem is if you want to create the UIPageViewController at a different time from when you first call `setViewControllers`. Most likely, the controller that contains the UIPageViewController is going to create it in `init` or `viewDidLoad`. But the true orientation isn't know at this point because apps are always started in portrait and then are sent rotation notifications if it's really in landscape. So, at the point most apps are going to create the UIPageViewController they don't know where the spine should be located.

Apple's sample calls `setViewControllers` at the same time as `initWithTransitionStyle`. This works in a trivial example like Apple's but most apps are probably going to dynamically load the content at a later time. If you haven't set any view controllers, then `spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation` isn't called.

So now you're stuck if you've already created the UIPageViewController with `initWithTransitionStyle`. You can't set the spine location and you have to insert exactly the correct number of view controllers for how you initialized the class when you didn't know the true orientation. If you set the wrong number of view controllers, it unhelpfully displays nothing on screen.

I see two possible solutions:

1. Always insert a dummy UIViewController right after calling `initWithTransitionStyle`. Having a view controller in there will cause it to respond to rotation events and `spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation` will be called.
2. Delay the create of the UIPageViewController until you are ready to set the actual content and the true orientation is known. This is what I chose.

Comment: Explained the problem i had when calling setViewControllers with an array bigger that 1. Haven't found anything else related to this problem on the web.

Comment: This actually explained the problem I was having and why, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

sample code for the answer provided by Totumus Maximus

```
NSDictionary *options =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
 [NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid]
                            forKey: UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];    
self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:options];
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me. I used the default project which is generated by apple page view template. But when I was using it inside navigation controller it was not displaying the spine properly so had to modify the initialization code which can be called from viewDidLoad method.

```
- (void)initializePageViewController
{
    int numberOfPagesPerScreen = 1;
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation))
      numberOfPagesPerScreen = 1;
    else
      numberOfPagesPerScreen = 2;       

    // for two-page layouts, we'll need to specify the spine location
    NSDictionary *pageViewOptions = nil;
    if(numberOfPagesPerScreen == 2)
      pageViewOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid], UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey, nil];  

    self.pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:pageViewOptions];
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;

    NSMutableArray *pageViewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];

    for(int pageViewIdx = 0; pageViewIdx < numberOfPagesPerScreen; pageViewIdx++) {
      MyPageViewController *pageController = [self.modelController viewControllerAtIndex:pageViewIdx storyboard:self.storyboard];
      [pageViewControllers addObject:pageController];
    }
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:pageViewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];

    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self.modelController;

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageViewController.view];

    // Set the page view controller's bounds using an inset rect so that self's view is visible around the edges of the pages.
    CGRect pageViewRect = self.view.bounds;
    pageViewRect = CGRectInset(pageViewRect, 40.0, 40.0);
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = pageViewRect;

    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    // Add the page view controller's gesture recognizers to the book view controller's view so that the gestures are started more easily.
    self.view.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers;
}
```