# Symbol not found: _UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'd like to have the page-curl animation when my app runs on iOS 5, for iOS 4-devices I made a custom animation.

I'm setting the spineLocation manually, as it didn't work otherwise (see: [UIPageViewController: pageViewController:spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation: not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755755/uipageviewcontroller-pageviewcontrollerspinelocationforinterfaceorientation-no)):

```
if ([UIPageViewController class]) {
   NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid], UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey, nil];
   ...
```

But that gives me at runtime on iOS4:

```
 Symbol not found: _UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey
```

The code isn't reached on iOS4-devices, nevertheless it crashes with that error message. What can I do to make that work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need to weak link to the `UIKit` framework. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010891), it looks like `UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey` is a static variable so checking for the object isn't enough to avoid the runtime error.

Comment: wow - should've known that by myself... but it didn't came to my mind ;) so: thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 0):

Don't weak-link UIKit unless you want a less-performant app, especially on startup!
For this specific problem you can work around with just using

`@"UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey"`

instead of the constant defined in UIKit. It's ugly, but it gets the job done without weak-linking the whole framework.