# UIPageViewController ios5 & ios6

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a navigation controller that has a `UIViewController` pushed onto it (**VC0**).

This VC0 has a `pageViewController` (**PVC**) property that uses either one (**VC1**) or two (**VC1** & **VC2**) "page slide" viewControllers dependant upon portrait or landscape device orientation.

This all seems to work fine in iOS6. In iOS 5 almost everything is fine too.

However, the problem I am having in iOS5 is if the device is landscape and the app opened when **VC0** is pushed and **PVC** created, spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation is not being called  **:(**

It does get called in iOS6.

Has anyone else come across this and found a work around?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755755/uipageviewcontroller-pageviewcontrollerspinelocationforinterfaceorientation-n

Comment: Thanks I had seen that, and it did help a little. What I've done so far to try and address this is initialise the pageViewContoller with either one or two viewControllers with appropriate spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation option dependant upon device orientation. Yet to test on iOS6 device but seems to work okay on iOS5 device and iOS6 simulator. Except I'm getting crashes sometime after  interaction when orientation is unknown at time of init.

Comment: You'd need to show us some code. You're crashing probably because something is set to nil, or when `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl` is set and you use `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationNone` (default), then that's invalid.